# Как при нажатии кнопки в боте телеграм, дать возможность пользователю ввести требуемые данные?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Помогите завершить код, пол дня убил на это, но так и не понял как реализовать то, что прописано в комментариях. Буду очень благодарен!

Хотя бы общей информацией поделитесь, или там просто наводки
Всему рад, за всё благодарен

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

TeleB = telebot.TeleBot('Token')

@TeleB.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def Start(Messages):

        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        key_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Создать заказ', callback_data="Order")
        markup.add(key_1)

        TeleB.send_message(Messages.chat.id, 'Пожелание', reply_markup = markup)

@ExTorg.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def Handler(CallBack):

    if CallBack.data == 'Order':

        Order = list()

        TeleB.send_message(CallBack.id, 'Введите название товара: ')

        ## Ожидаем отправку сообщения с именем товара от пользователя и заносим текст сообщения в список Order.append('Текст отправленного сообщения'), после чего удаляем сообщение отправленное пользователем, затем продолжаем выполнение кода

        TeleB.edit_message_text(chat_id = CallBack.id, message_id = CallBack.message.id, text = 'Введите стоймость товара: ')

        ## Ожидаем отправку сообщения со стоймостью товара от пользователя и заносим текст сообщения в список Order.append('Текст отправленного сообщения'), после чего удаляем сообщение отправленное пользователем, затем продолжаем выполнение кода

        TeleB.edit_message_text(chat_id = CallBack.id, message_id = CallBack.message.id, text = 'Введите описание товара: ')

        ## Ожидаем отправку сообщения с описанием товара от пользователя и заносим текст сообщения в список Order.append('Текст отправленного сообщения'), после чего удаляем сообщение отправленное пользователем, затем продолжаем выполнение кода

        Blank = f'Имя товара: {Order[0]}\nСтоймость товара: {Order[1]}\nОписание товара: {Order[2]}\n\nСохранить позицию?'

        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        key_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Да', callback_data="Order_Yes")
        key_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Нет', callback_data="Order_No")
        markup.add(key_1, key_2)

        TeleB.edit_message_text(chat_id = CallBack.id, message_id = CallBack.message.id, text = 'Введите название товара: ', reply_markup = markup)

        ## Ожидаем подтверждения. Если нажата кнопка 'Да', то переменная Order передаётся в функцию Save, иначе действие завершается без сохранения

def Save(Order):
    print(Order)
```

Comment: использовать машину состояний

Comment: Спасибо большое)
Буду разбираться, я не знал о такой возможности. Не давно начал этим заниматься. Тренируюсь. Набираюсь опыта только

Answer (score 1):

без оптимизаций:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Создать заказ', callback_data="order")
    markup.add(key_1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пожелание', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def handler(call):
    if call.data == 'order':
        msg = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Введите название товара: ')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, product_name)

    elif call.data == 'order_Yes':
        save(order)
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, 'Yes')

    else:
        print('else')
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, 'else')


def product_name(message):
    order.append(message.text)
    sleep(1)
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)

    msg = bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id - 1,
                                text='Введите стоимость товара: ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, product_price)


def product_price(message):
    order.append(message.text)
    sleep(1)
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)

    msg = bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id - 2,
                                text='Введите описание товара: ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, product_description)


def product_description(message):
    order.append(message.text)
    sleep(1)
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data="order_Yes")
    key_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data="order_No")
    markup.add(key_1, key_2)

    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id - 3,
                          text=f'Имя товара: {order[0]}\nСтоймость товара: {order[1]}\n'
                               f'Описание товара: {order[2]}\n\nСохранить позицию?', reply_markup=markup)


def save(order_list):
    print(order_list)
```