# Как получить текст от пользователя после нажатия на кнопку в inline клавиатуре pyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я делаю простого бота в телеграмм, который сможет добавлять и сохранять моих должников. У меня возникла проблема на моменте получения от пользователя данных. Когда пользователь доходит до момента выбора валюты бот отправляет ему сообщение с кнопками на одной из которых написано "другое". После нажатия на эту кнопку, я хочу чтобы пользователь мог ввести текст, а я этот текст уже потом сохраню в базу. Подскажите как реализовать

```
class Debtor:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.amount = None
        self.user = None

# начало работы с пользователем
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    con = sqlite3.connect('tg_bd.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        'insert into all_users (chat_id, first_name, second_name, username) values ({}, "{}", "{}", "{}")'.format(
            message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name, message.from_user.last_name,
            message.from_user.username))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Hello, ' + message.from_user.first_name)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_message(message):
    con = sqlite3.connect('tg_bd.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    user = cur.execute('select * from all_users where chat_id = "{}"'.format(message.from_user.id)).fetchall()[0]
    try:
        if message.text == '/my_debtors':
            debtors = cur.execute('select * from my_debtors where user = "{}"'.format(user[1])).fetchall()
            if debtors:
                debtors_mess = 'Твои должники:\n'
                for i in debtors:
                    debtors_mess += '{} {}\n'.format(i[1], i[2])
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, debtors_mess)
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Поздравляю, у тебя нет должников!')
        if message.text == '/add_debtor':
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите имя')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, add_debtor_name)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)


def add_debtor_name(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        name = message.text
        debtor = Debtor(name)
        debtor_dict[chat_id] = debtor
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите сумму')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, add_debtor_amount)
    except Exception as ex:
        bot.send_message(message, 'OoOoOops')


def add_debtor_amount(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        amount = message.text
        if not amount.isdigit():
            msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Неверный формат данных')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, add_debtor_amount)
            return
        debtor = debtor_dict[chat_id]
        debtor.amount = message.text
        debtor_dict[chat_id] = debtor
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, add_currency)
    except Exception as ex:
        bot.send_message(message, 'OoOoOops')

# Здесь отправляется сообщение с кнопками
def add_currency(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        debtor = debtor_dict[chat_id]
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите валюту', reply_markup=gen_currency_markup())
        # add_debtor_in_base(debtor)
    except Exception as ex:
        bot.send_message(message, 'OoOoOops')

# Здесь по идее должен обрабатываться ответ от пользователя
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_query(call):
    if call.data == "cur_usd":
        debtor = debtor_dict[call.from_user.id]
        debtor.currency = 'usd'
    elif call.data == 'cur_eur':
        debtor = debtor_dict[call.from_user.id]
        debtor.currency = 'eur'
    elif call.data == 'cur_rub':
        debtor = debtor_dict[call.from_user.id]
        debtor.currency = 'rub'
    elif call.data == 'cur_another':

    print(debtor.currency)
    bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, 'Я запомню это')

# Сами кнопки для сообщения
def gen_currency_markup():
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.row_width = 3
    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton("EUR", callback_data='cur_eur'),
               InlineKeyboardButton("USD", callback_data='cur_usd'),
               InlineKeyboardButton("RUB", callback_data='cur_rub'))
    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton('Другое', callback_data='cur_another'))
    return markup
```

Comment: использовать машину состояний и писать ботов на аиограм

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1338160/234134

Answer (score 0):

В версии [4.1.1](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/releases/tag/4.1.1) появились `states` - *состояния*.

Можно установить *состояние* в функции, которая отслеживает нажатие кнопки "другое", а потом ловить сообщения, фильтруя по нему.

[Пример из репозитория](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/custom_states.py):

```python
    @bot.message_handler(state=1)
    def name_get(message):
        """
        State 1. Will process when user's state is 1.
        """
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Now write me a surname')
        bot.set_state(message.chat.id, 2)
        with bot.retrieve_data(message.chat.id) as data:
            data['name'] = message.text
     
     
    @bot.message_handler(state=2)
    def ask_age(message):
        """
        State 2. Will process when user's state is 2.
        """
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "What is your age?")
        bot.set_state(message.chat.id, 3)
        with bot.retrieve_data(message.chat.id) as data:
            data['surname'] = message.text
```